# Asynchronous operation and populating properties

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I am writing a weather app and I have two classes for parsing the JSON data. The first class is JSONDownloader, it's job is simply download the JSON data given a url and return a URLSessionTask.

```
class JSONDownloader {

    let session: URLSession

    init(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration) {
        self.session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(configuration: .default)
    }

    func jsonTask(url: URL, completeHandler completion: @escaping ([String: AnyObject]?) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                return
            }

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                print("200 code")
                if let data = data {

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
                        completion(json)
                    } catch {
                        print("*****error*****")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return task
    }
}
```

The other class is DarkSkyClient, which takes whatever data downloaded from JSONDownloader and interprets it, the code is below

```
class DarkSkyClient {

    let downloader = JSONDownloader()
    fileprivate let key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    lazy var baseUrl: URL = {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/\(self.key)")!
        return url
    }()

    func fetchData(condition: Condition, coordinate: Coordinate, completionHandler completion: @escaping (WeatherForecastData) -> Void) {

        guard let url = URL(string: coordinate.description, relativeTo: baseUrl) else {
            return
        }

        let task = downloader.jsonTask(url: url) { (jsonWeather) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let weatherJson = jsonWeather else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                switch condition {
                case .currently :
                    let currentlyWeather = WeatherForecastData(json: weatherJson["currently"] as! [String: AnyObject])
                    completion(currentlyWeather)
                case .hourly :
                    print("hourly weather")

                case .minutely :
                    print("minutely weather")

                }
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Now, here is the problem, in my main view controller:

```
let client = DarkSkyClient()
var coordinate: Coordinate?
var weatherData: WeatherForecastData?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let coordinate = coordinate {
        client.fetchData(condition: .currently, coordinate: coordinate) { [unowned self] (weather) in

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.weatherData = weather
                print("\(self.weatherData?.summary)")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign `weatherData` to what the closure returns in the completion handler which is `weather`. However, when I test to see if `weatherData` is `nil` using a print statement, it came back as `nil`. How do I assign the `weather` variable from a closure to my `weatherData` variable in my view controller?

Comment: use completionHandler

Comment: I did, but it is not working

Comment: You have not provide enough information to help. What code is actually called? What results are there at each step? Use the debugger and step through the code and see what is actually happening and figure out where things go wrong. Then [edit] your question with those details.

Comment: There is at least one path in your `jsonTask` function that returns without printing an error and without calling the completion handler. Set breakpoints in your completion handlers and single step through to see what is happening.

Comment: What does `WeatherForecastData` look like?